# OnMouseOver event in Coqsoft treegrid cell

Tags: javascript, treegrid

Does anybody know if Treegrid supports OnMouseOver event?
I need make an ajax call on mouse-over which might be compute intensive.
Thanks

Comment: This is a Javascript Question, not a Java Question.

Comment: I don't know whether the product itself supports the event - you'd have to refer to the documentation or wait whether anybody turns up here who knows it - but if all else fails, you can certainly assign such an event through the DOM. That would be very cumbersome to get to, though, looking at the code: http://www.treegrid.com/treegrid/www/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is support for OnMouseOver. You can check the [events and actions](http://www.treegrid.com/treegrid/Doc/Events.htm?mark=events#Events) section on their documentation for more information.